# Tune GAMs based on multiple formulas using the mlr3 package

Tags: r, mlr3

I would like to tune a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) based on several formulas associated with different combinations of k (i.e., dimension of the basis used to represent the smooth term).
I am using a grid search to accomplish this. However, I encountered the following error message:

```
Error: 'TunerGridSearch' does not support param types: 'ParamUty'
```

How can I **test several formulas to tune GAMs** ? I'm sorry, I'm new to machine learning models.

Here is a reproducible example using the `mlr3` package:

### UPDATE:

```
## Install the learner "classif.gam"
## Useful link: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners
## https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_learners_classif.gam.html
remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3extralearners@*release")
install_learners("classif.gam")

## Task
task_sonar = tsk("sonar")
## summary(task_sonar)

## Search space
search_space <- paradox::ps(formula = paradox::p_uty(c("Class ~ s(V15, k = 1)", "Class ~ s(V15, k = 2)")))

## Learner
learner <- mlr3extralearners::lrn("classif.gam", predict_type = "prob")

## Performance measure
measure <- mlr3::msr("classif.auc")

## Terminator
terminator <- mlr3tuning::trm("none")

## Tuner
tuner <- mlr3tuning::tnr("grid_search")

## Resampling
resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)
inner_resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)
outer_resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)

## Run an automatic tuning process
at = mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = tuner,
                            learner = learner,
                            resampling = resampling,
                            measure = measure,
                            search_space = search_space,
                            terminator = terminator)

at$train(task_sonar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not have access to `mlr3extralearners` since it is not in CRAN. I used `kknn` instead since it also has a hyperparameter `k`

I think the error comes from defining the formula inside the `search_space`.

To obtain the formula (`Class ~ V15`) subset  the dataset or use a suitable [pipe operator](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter7/sequential_pipelines.html). Then define the tuning range for `k` as a `p_int()` (See the [mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter4/hyperparameter_optimization.html) on this).

Code:

```
library(mlr3verse)
library(tidyverse)

## take the data and reduce it to the variables of interest
df <- tsk("sonar")$data()
df_red <- df %>% select("Class", "V15")

## define the task (Class ~ V15)
task_sonar <- as_task_classif(
  df_red,
  target="Class",
  id = "sonar"
)

learner <- lrn("classif.kknn", predict_type="prob")

## create searchspace independently of task
search_space <- ps(
  k=p_int(1,2)
)

## Performance measure
measure <- mlr3::msr("classif.auc")

## Terminator
terminator <- mlr3tuning::trm("none")

## Tuner
tuner <- mlr3tuning::tnr("grid_search")

## Resampling
resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)
inner_resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)
outer_resampling <- rsmp ("cv", folds = 5)

## Run an automatic tuning process
at = mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = tuner,
                            learner = learner,
                            resampling = resampling,
                            measure = measure,
                            search_space = search_space,
                            terminator = terminator)

at$train(task_sonar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There is no parameter 'k' for the learner `classif.gam`, so I think I have to vary the parameter 'formula' with different formulas (e.g. 'Class ~ s(V15, k = 1)', 'Class ~ s(V15, k = 2)'), but I'm not sure if it's really possible to construct a search space with different formulas since I'm getting an error message. I have updated the code to download the `mlr3extralearners` package.

Comment: @Pierre I see the issue now. Reffer to https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/237, which  is inherited from https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2177. An other possiblility might be using `model.matrix()` https://rdrr.io/r/stats/model.matrix.html in a pipeoperator. Alternatively for a small search space you could create different tasks and benchmark them https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/benchmark.html i.e. use the benchmark looping to choose good parametrizations for k instead of `auto_tuner()`.

Comment: DuesserBaest Thank you very much for your help. That's great. I'm currently figuring out how to do the second solution. However, there's no `formula` argument in the `makeClassifTask` function. So, instead of creating multiple tasks, I'm going to create multiple learners (since there's a `formula` argument in the `gam` function) like this: `learner_gam_1 = mlr3extralearners::lrn("classif.gam", predict_type = "prob", formula = tested_formula_1), learner_gam_2 = mlr3extralearners::lrn("classif.gam", predict_type = "prob", formula = tested_formula_2).`